# Is there a good way to encourage people to post metrics?

Tags: discussion

After reading and trying to answer a question on [paying attention to page load metrics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-much-attention-should-i-pay-to-page-load-metrics) I'm wondering if there is any way to encourage people to post their metrics when they ask certain questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just post a comment to that effect. Something like:

> I can answer this in a generic way,
>   but to really be able to help you, I
>   need you to post relevant parts of
>   ....

Its then up to them. This is in no way different from SO .. to help someone there, we need to see the code and the results.